# Spread operator on array of objects returns empty array

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, redux, redux-persist

> TL;DR: If value is unexpectedly gone or undefined or null etc. go and see the async functions.

There are some questions about spread operator returning "undefined" but in my case I got absolutely nothing.

This is the process

1. Function A is an async function and returns a `[listof_objA, listof_objB]`
2. After function is evaluated the results are used like `.then(([listof_objA, listof_objB])=> { ...so on`
3. it is then dispatched `dispatch(setListA(listof_objA))` like

```
someAsyncFunc().then(([listof_objA, listof_objB])=> {
  dispatch(setListA(listof_objA))
  dispatch(setListB(listof_objB))
})
```

4. In the reducer when `console.log(action.payload)`, it correctly displays the obtained `listof_objA`
5. At first I did this:

```
case Types.SET_LISTA: {
    console.log(action.payload)
    return {
      ...state,
      listof_objA: action.payload
    }
  }
```

6. Which correctly set the listof_objA to the new value but did not cause a re-rendering because of the reference not changing (Found out from another question)
7. So I changed it to this:

```
case Types.SET_LISTA: {
    console.log(action.payload)
    return {
        ...state,
        listof_objA: [...action.payload]
    }
  }
```

8. Now suddenly listof_objA becomes an empty list! Ex) `[]`. The `action.payload` still correctly displays the obtained `listof_objA`.
9. I have tried `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(action.payload))`, `const newList = [...action.payload]`
10. But all cloning returns an empty array.
11. I observed more in the redux-logger. The collapsed action shows the payload is `Array(0)` but when dropped down it shows `Array(13) [{...},{...}, ... , {...}]`.

This is it. I couldn't find any solution. I don't know why this is happening. And it seems it happened only to me. Please help. If you need anymore information please comment. I am working with a company so I can't provide all information. But I'll try my best. Thank you.

Comment: Where are you writing dispatch would be my only question here? Is dispatch inside a `.then` of promise or out of that promise, that would let me understand this behavior a bit more

Comment: @pavankumar I've updated the question. Look below index 3. Thank you.

Comment: Okay why are the variables `listof_...` wrapped around `[]` ? And try doing `console.log` before dispatch and let me know

Comment: I had to return two lists from the async function. So I put both list in a list since you can't return multiple variables in JS. `listof_objA and B` both correctly has list of objects as intended before the dispatch. The values disappear only when I try to copy the lists.

Comment: It shouldn't ideally return like that but if you have a reproducible example maybe I can help you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are using a Promise in `someAsyncFunc`, If so, the reason you get an empty array is because you probably didn't resolved your Promise chain correctly.

The correct Promise chain should look like this:

```
async function someAsyncFunc() {
    return await fetch('ENDPOINT')
        .then(response => {
            return response.ok
                ? response.json()
                : Promise.reject(Error('Unsuccessful response'));
        })
        .then(([listof_objA, listof_objB]) => {
            dispatch(setListA(listof_objA));
            dispatch(setListB(listof_objB));
        });
}
```

In order to read the body of the responses JSON. You need to call the response.json() method. The json() method reads the full body of the response and parses the text as a JSON. Since this is another asynchronous operation it returns a promise itself.

Hope that it helps

Answer (score 1):

@jank answer I expect solves your problem, but you might want to take a look at [redux-api-middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-api-middleware) as a much simpler way of doing RPC calls, without all the promises.